# How to turn my JSON result into an array or object

Tags: json, swift3, ios10, xcode8.2

I have been searching every where, but cannot get to the right answer. I receive a Json result with the following structure

```
    {
    result =     {
        "2ab5a003-0120-4c01-80f2-a237dcf4ba14" =         {
            icon = garden;
            id = "2ab5a003-0120-4c01-80f2-a237dcf4ba14";
            index = 1;
            name = "Tafel hoek";
            parent = "855113f1-f488-4223-b675-2f01270f573e";
        };
        "2afd6093-ca6d-4e52-aaca-336ab76ea454" =         {
            icon = default;
            id = "2afd6093-ca6d-4e52-aaca-336ab76ea454";
            index = 11;
            name = Badkamer;
            parent = "9919ee1e-ffbc-480b-bc4b-77fb047e9e68";
        }; 
};
    status = 200;
}
```

Because I don't know the 1st key in the result I am lost to get the separate items. Is there any one who can help me ? Thanks in advance

my code is:

{               print("Error: ")
                print(error!)

```
        } else {  // no error


            if let urlContent = data {  // 3

                do {  // 4

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    print(json)


                } catch {

                    print("JSON processing failed")

                }  // end 4 do

            }  // end 3 let urlContent

        }  // end 2 if error}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the dictionary for key `result`, you can enumerate it as usual:

```
if let result = json["result"] as? [String:[String:Any]] {
    for (key, value) in result {
       let name = value["name"] as! String
       let index = value["index"] as! Int
       print (key, name, index)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. However if I use that code, I get the remark that for both name & index "type 'Any' has no subscript members"

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code ,i think that is not  a valid json format and tell me where you are struggling to parse.ignore that key and try as usual

Comment: see here my code, I posted in the original question